# iOS: show info to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a map with different annotation, I got this information from json and server, I can show status of my information to the map, I want to show it in my table also, my table implementation is correct, when I used this Array, I can show all these information to my table :

```
 recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full 
Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", nil];
```

but I do not know how to show "status" in table:

```
newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
newAnnotation.subtitle = dictionary[@"company"];
newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"];



 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

 //  recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full 
Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", nil];

_mapView.delegate = self;

[ApiManager fetchCoordinates:^(id result) {


    newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    NSArray *array=(NSArray*)result;


    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {

        // create the annotation
        MyAnnotation *newAnnotation;


        newAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        newAnnotation.subtitle = dictionary[@"company"];
        newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"];



        [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotations:newAnnotations];

 } failure:^(NSError *error) {

 }];
 }
```

Appreciated any code in answer part, Thanks in advance!

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath
 *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Item";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  
reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Update :

I want to add this  newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"]; to recipes or what ever NSArray or ... to show it on table

Comment: What is the relationship between `recipes` and `status`?

Comment: @Paulw11 nothing, recipes is NSArray and status is located here    newAnnotation.status = dictionary[@"status"]; and newAnnotation is added to   [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation]; since newAnnotations is NSMutableArray

Comment: If there is no relationship then how do want to show the status in the table? Do you want status in its own row?  As a heading or footer?  Displayed in every row?

Comment: @Paulw11 just want to show it as cell textLabel,cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: @Paulw11 all these information are located to newAnnotations that it is a NSMutableArray, how can I use this NSMutableArray and show all information?

Comment: You need to store you annotations somewhere other than a local array - i.e. a property.  You can then access the data from within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: You need to store you annotations somewhere other than a local array - i.e. a property.  You can then access the data from within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Zhang would you please add your solution with the code to the answer part

Comment: @Paulw11 would you please write your solution in answer part

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this in your CellForRowAtIndexPathMethod do this

MyAnnotation *newAnnotation=[newAnnotations objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

then 
just use it as

cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",newAnnotaion.Status];